# Multi-dimensional Array - PHP - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm joining 3 tables to get following results from database using CodeIgniter and Jamie Rumbelow's My_Model:

```
Career_Option            Course               Specialization
-------------            -------              --------------
Management               MBA                  Finance
Management               BBA                  Marketing
Engineering              BSc                  Computer Science
Engineering              MSc                  Bio-Technology
```

This is how my resultset looks when passed to controller from my model class:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [career_option] => Management
            [course] => MBA
            [specialization] => Finance
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [career_option] => Management
            [course] => BBA
            [specialization] => Marketing
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [career_option] => Engineering
            [course] => Bsc
            [specialization] => Computer Science
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [career_option] => Engineering
            [course] => MSc
            [specialization] => Bio-Technology
        )
)
```

Now, on my web page I wanna show this result set in following manner:

```
Management
|
|_ MBA
|   |
|   |_ Finance
|
|_ BBA
    |
    |_ Marketing

Engineering
|
|_ BSc
|   |
|   |_ Computer Science
|
|_ MSc
    | 
    |_ Bio-Technology
```

Could you suggest me the way I should create an array (multi-dimensional??) in controller to hold these records which I would eventually pass to my view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say for example your array is in a variable called `$results`, you could do the following

```
$aData['careerOptions'] = array();
foreach($results as $result) {
    if(!in_array($result->career_option, $aData['careerOptions'])) {
        $aData['careerOptions'][] = $result->career_option;
    }
    if(!in_array($result->course, $aData['careerOptions'][$result->career_option])) {
        $aData['careerOptions'][$result->career_option][] = $result->course;
    }
    if(!in_array($result->specialization, $aData['careerOptions'][$result->career_option][$result->course])) {
        $aData['careerOptions'][$result->career_option][$result->course][] = $result->specialization;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass `$aData` to your view by doing

```
$this->load->view('path/to/view', $aData);
```

Once in your view you'll have access to `$careerOptions` that will contain your array

Answer (score 0):

Does that work for you?

```
function tree_from_rows($rows)
{
    $tree = array();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $ref =& $tree;
        foreach($row as $value) {
            if (!array_key_exists($value, $ref)) {
                $ref[$value] = array();
            }
            $ref =& $ref[$value];
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Note that the most inner branches are arrays too, so when iterating the array you need to use only indices.